# Nginx + LAMP прикрыть доступ к порту 8080

Tags: apache, nginx, lamp, centos

Имею сконфигурированный **Nginx (frontend) + LAMP**, несколько доменов (virtual hosts).

**Nginx** сидит на **80** порту, а **Apache** - на **8080**.

Так выглядит у меня конфиг **Nginx**:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;

        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 10m;
    }

    location ~ ^/phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png))$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/$1;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|flv|rtf|js|swf|iso)$ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;

        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 10m;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|flv|rtf|js|swf|iso)$ {
        root /var/www/example.com;
    }
}
```

А так - конфиг апача:

```
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
    Options -Indexes
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Как запретить доступ при переходе по ссылке вида: **example.com:8080**?

При переходе по ссылке вида:

**exmaple.com** = [скрин1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAggh.png)

**exmaple.com:8080** = [скрин2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvquy.png)

И какие, на ваш взгляд, мои ошибки в конфиге? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: @IFursov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
```

?

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!